# Imagick not loading

Tags: php

So I just installed `imagemagic` using homebrew and then also linked to php.ini file.

However, if I run `php` command on terminal now, I get this error :-

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php71-imagick/3.4.3_4/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71-imagick/3.4.3_4/imagick.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php71-imagick/3.4.3_4/imagick.so
  Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm unable to understand it. What might be the reason for this error?

Comment: Have you tried searching here for "imagick homebrew" or "imagick install"?

Answer (score 0):

I have the save problem, and this solution helps me:

`brew reinstall -s php71-imagick`